# Find the route based on the postion and the arrival time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the route number  from the `routes` or   `arrivaltimes` table based on the position and arrivaltime of the bus. I have 3 tables `route`, `stops`, `arrivaltime`. In stops table  `route_id` is the foreign key as well in arrivaltimes table `stop_id` .  Is that possiable with my current database desgin? How can I  query that?

I have resently added the route table to define the stop's order of the routes. I am using the harvsin formula to calculate the distance.

I appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As an aside, consider storing Mon-Sun as a bitwise integer where 1 = 'Monday', 2 = 'Tuesday', 4 = 'Wednesday', 8 = 'Thursday' and 127 = everyday. And no pictures please. Just proper DDLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join your arrivaltimes_table with your stopstable based on the stop_id column, and filter based on lat, longi, and arrivaltime.  For example:

```
select a.route
from arrivaltimes_table a
join stopstable s on a.stop_id = s.stop_id
where s.lat = 53.868937
and s.longi = 10.665545
and a.arrivaltime = '12:25:00';
```

That should return route 1.  If you want the route_id instead, use `select s.route_id`.  If you want to look only for a certain day, filter on the a.weekday column.  For example, to find the route that stops at a particular location at a particular time on Sunday:

```
select a.route
from arrivaltimes_table a
join stopstable s on a.stop_id = s.stop_id
where s.lat = 53.868937
and s.longi = 10.665545 
and a.weekday = 'sun'
and a.arrivaltime = '12:25:00';
```

Comment: what is `a` in your answer? And how can I find the direction?

Comment: Ok`a` is arrivaltimes table

Comment: `select arrivaltimes.route
from arrivaltimes 
join stops  on arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id
where stops.lat = 53.868937
and stops.longi = 10.665545
and arrivaltimes.arrivaltime = '12:25:00';` but I am getting all these  routes `1
9
3
9
7
31`

Comment: Well, you've only shown a subset of your rows, but I assume that means that you have multiple routes that stop at that location and time, but they stop on different days.  So add "and a.weekday = 'sun'" for example, to find those that stop on Sunday.